# How does the choice of norm affect the condition of a problem?

Tags: numerics

we know that for a differentiable problem, the absolute condition number is the norm of its jacobian i.e. ||J||. We also know that a well-conditioned problem typically has a small condition number.

However, we get different results for different types of norm we pick to calculate condition number. 
How should we decide on the appropriate norm to use and assess the condition number based on the norm?